# Python structured looping over multiple items

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to loop over three lists

```
['A','B'],[1,2],[3,4]
```

If I wanted to loop over all possibilities, I could have done this:

```
for i,j,k in zip(['A','B'],[1,2],[3,4])
```

However, I want to loop in a certain manner. I want to iterate over 
`'A',1 and 'B',2` for all possible values of the last list. Thus I want to exclude the combinations

```
 'A',2 and 'B',1.
```

Basically I want to generate the following items.
`'A',1,3 'A',1,4 'B',2,3 B',2,4`

I am clueless on how to do it.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for ..can you please add more example

Comment: What **_is_** the order you want to loop in?

Comment: any order is fine..i want to enumerate all the possibilities

Comment: @rahul_88 could you provide an example of what you expect the output of this loop to be?

Comment: @HariomSingh I added the iterates I require

Comment: @JonClements I just did....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to keep 'a' tied together with 1, and 'b' with 2, you should zip the first two lists together. And because you want to iterate over 3 and 4 regardless of which choice you make in the first part, that should be a separate iteration, not part of the zip.

```
[(i,j,k) for k in [3, 4] for i,j in zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2])]

# [('a', 1, 3), ('b', 2, 3), ('a', 1, 4), ('b', 2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
for a,b in product(zip(l1,l2), l3):
        print (a[0], a[1], b)

A 1 3
A 1 4
B 2 3
B 2 4
```

Comment: If you're using `product` from the `itertools` library, you may want to add that. No sure though, so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I just did ;) sorry

Comment: it produces exactly your pairs. you only need to unpack differently

Comment: This would work if you did something like: `(i, j), k = a, b`.